# How to integrate Google Image Search API in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to integrate Google Image Search API in iPhone SDK?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [link](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/index.html) to get introduced with google image search api

and read this for [json](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html)

its too easy inn response u will get unescapedUrl key is your url where image lies.

Answer (score 0):

By calling the API as detailed in the [documentation.](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/index.html)